# Fontify R code blocks in Org-mode 8

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I am trying to change the background color of R code blocks in Org-mode 8. In Org-mode 7, I was able to use:

```
(defface org-block-background
   '((t (:background "#dadada")))
   "Face used for the source block background.")
```

But the `org-block-background` variable seems to have disappeared in version 8...?

I tried:

```
(defface org-block
   '((t (:background "#dadada")))
   "Face used for the source block background.")
```

which works for:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC
#+END_SRC
```

and

```
#+BEGIN_latex
#+END_latex
```

But for some reason, the background color disappears, the moment I specify a language, e.g...

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R
#+END_SRC
```

I am working on a mac, running Emacs 24.3 and have upgraded org-mode to v8, using:

```
cd ~/.emacs.d/lisp
git clone git://orgmode.org/org-mode.git
cd org-mode
make autoloads
make
make doc
```

Here is the config from my init.el file:

```
;;;----- Startup ----------------------------;

;;; Add src directory to path
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")

;;;----- Org-Mode ---------------------------;

;;; Add upgraded org-mode to load path
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/org-mode/lisp")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/org-mode/contrib/lisp" t)

;;; fontify code in code blocks
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)

(defface org-block-begin-line
  '((t (:foreground "#666666" :background "#dadada")))
  "Face used for the line delimiting the begin of source blocks.")

(defface org-block
  '((t (:background "#dadada")))
  "Face used for the source block background.")

(defface org-block-end-line
  '((t (:foreground "#666666" :background "#dadada")))
  "Face used for the line delimiting the end of source blocks.")

(require 'org)

;;;----- ESS/R ------------------------------;

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/ess/lisp/")
(load "ess-site")

;;;------ Babel ------------------------------;

;;; Support R
(org-babel-do-load-languages
  'org-babel-load-languages
  '((R . t)
    (latex . t)))

;;;----- Look & feel ----------------------------;

;;; Set default theme
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")
(load-theme 'solarized-light t)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Place your cursor on the point that you want to change the font, and type `C-u C-x =`, and that will tell you (among other things) the name of the fonts at that point.  Then you can `M-x customize-face` the font you want to change, or manually change it in your `.emacs` file.

Comment: Thanks! When I place my cursor over a generic #+BEGIN_SRC/#+END_SRC block, I get [this printout](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4poyb4ymlwe22x5/begin_src.png?dl=0). But when I do the same thing over a #+BEGIN_SRC R/#+END_SRC block, I get [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfow57b60gz5uvp/begin_src_r.png?dl=0). The second one appears to be missing the `face:org-block` property...?

Comment: I think you found it -- go ahead and try modifying `org-block` (e.g., "*Face text in #+begin ... #+end blocks.*") and see if that helps -- `M-x customize-face RET org-block RET`  On my Emacs-Trunk developer snapshot, it shows inheriting `shadow`.  So you can remove the inheriting and set it to whatever you want, or modify `shadow` instead.

Comment: After you save the customization for future usage, go ahead and open up your `.emacs` file and take a peek regarding how it is customized as to `org-block` or `shadow` depending upon which you decided.  Then you can copy that relevant section over to your `init.el` and get rid of your `.emacs` file if everything is already in your `init.el`.  Back it up of course (just in case . . .), before you dust it.

Comment: Modifying org-block works fine for #+BEGIN_SRC/END_SRC. The problem I'm running into is that, once I specify a language (i.e., #+BEGIN_SRC R) Emacs no longer recognizes this code as an org-block. Take a look at [this screen recording](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rotbw4fv42juv8l/fontify_demo.mov?dl=0). Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The highlighting of the arrow `->` and the string `'...'` look to me as if the source code block would be in `R-mode`. Something like `org-mode` with `poly-mode`? (see https://github.com/vitoshka/polymode#Screenshots). Cool!

Comment: `org-block-background` face has been removed in org 8.3.1 Currently it seems the only way to get this behavior back if you're using the old version is to manually reverse the change introduced. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out I had cloned an old branch of org-mode which was missing the `org-block-background` variable! Deleted my org-mode folder and reinstalled using:

```
cd ~/.emacs.d/lisp
git clone https://github.com/Konubinix/org-mode.git
cd org-mode
make autoloads
make
make doc
```

Then revised my init.el to read:

```
;;;----- Org-Mode ---------------------------;


;;; Add upgraded org-mode to load path
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/org-mode/lisp")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/org-mode/contrib/lisp" t)

;;; fontify code in code blocks
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)

(defface org-block-begin-line
  '((t (:foreground "#666666" :background "#dadada")))
  "Face used for the line delimiting the begin of source blocks.")

(defface org-block
  '((t (:background "#dadada")))
  "Face used for the source block background.")

(defface org-block-background
  '((t (:background "#dadada")))
  "Face used for the source block background.")

(defface org-block-end-line
  '((t (:foreground "#666666" :background "#dadada")))
  "Face used for the line delimiting the end of source blocks.")

(require 'org)
```

And presto!

Comment: This is no longer current.  See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

FYI, this will not work for current versions of Org Mode (from the Git master branch), after this commit http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=f8b42e8 - at least until something changes.  This is announced [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2014-07/msg00380.html) (July, 2014) and continues to be in effect for Org Mode users, e.g. see [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-04/msg00686.html) (April, 2015).  Anyone dedicated to restoring the old behavior locally might be able to do it from the commit's diff - I haven't tried.  Future versions of Org Mode may restore the feature, possibly going about it in a different way.  For now, this is about all you can get:

[image]

(The first SRC block above gets a background from my setting for `org-block`.)

Answer (score 3):

Turns out `org-block-background` face has been removed in org version 8.3.1 in commit `f8b42e8`, thus the bug. The rationale seems to be

1. it causes a bug with `ps` export
2. it's inefficient

Maybe in the future there will be an alternative, but not yet.

[Fontify R code blocks in Org-mode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290924/fontify-r-code-blocks-in-org-mode-8)

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-08/msg00510.html

Currently it seems the only way to get the old behavior back is to manually reverse the changes introduced in commit `f8b42e8`. You can see the commit here:

http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/commit/?id=f8b42e8

```
diff --git a/lisp/org-faces.el b/lisp/org-faces.el
index e693dab..83453e8 100644
--- a/lisp/org-faces.el
+++ b/lisp/org-faces.el
@@ -537,9 +537,6 @@ follows a #+DATE:, #+AUTHOR: or #+EMAIL: keyword."
   :group 'org-faces
   :version "22.1")

-(defface org-block-background '((t ()))
-  "Face used for the source block background.")
-
 (org-copy-face 'org-meta-line 'org-block-begin-line
   "Face used for the line delimiting the begin of source blocks.")

diff --git a/lisp/org.el b/lisp/org.el
index a153151..7e30061 100644
--- a/lisp/org.el
+++ b/lisp/org.el
@@ -5930,15 +5930,7 @@ by a #."
          (cond
           ((and lang (not (string= lang "")) org-src-fontify-natively)
        (org-src-font-lock-fontify-block lang block-start block-end)
-       ;; remove old background overlays
-       (mapc (lambda (ov)
-           (if (eq (overlay-get ov 'face) 'org-block-background)
-               (delete-overlay ov)))
-             (overlays-at (/ (+ beg1 block-end) 2)))
-       ;; add a background overlay
-       (setq ovl (make-overlay beg1 block-end))
-                (overlay-put ovl 'face 'org-block-background)
-                (overlay-put ovl 'evaporate t)) ; make it go away when empty
+       (add-text-properties beg1 block-end '(src-block t)))
           (quoting
        (add-text-properties beg1 (min (point-max) (1+ end1))
                     '(face org-block))) ; end of source block
@@ -21828,9 +21820,7 @@ and end of string."
 When INSIDE is non-nil, don't consider we are within a src block
 when point is at #+BEGIN_SRC or #+END_SRC."
   (let ((case-fold-search t) ov)
-    (or (and (setq ov (overlays-at (point)))
-        (memq 'org-block-background
-          (overlay-properties (car ov))))
+    (or (and (eq (get-char-property (point) 'src-block) t))
    (and (not inside)
         (save-match-data
           (save-excursion
```